# Why isn't my while loop closing even though the End While is there?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a simple linear search with a while loop. But, for some reason an error is coming up on the end while line.

```
While (i < 32 And found = False)    
    SNAddress = "E" + (63 + i)

    If Range(SNAddress).Value = DAInput Then
        found = True
        assignAddress = "G" + (63 + i)
        statusLocation = "H" + (63 + i)
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
End While
```

The compile error is saying that it is expecting a while or an end of statement, when I believe that I have both.

Comment: `Wend` not `End While` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement

Comment: Too easy, thanks so much

Comment: Or the modern equivalent `Do While ... Loop` or one of its variants